# Sails.js User model not deleting password

Tags: json, sails.js

I am trying to remove the password from the JSON serialized User model.

For some reason my controller returning `res.json({user: myUser});` is returning the full user including the password. Below is my User model. Thoughts?

```
# models/User.js
var User = {
  attributes: {
    username: 'string',
    password: 'string'
  },

  // Override toJSON method to remove password from API
  toJSON: function() {
    var obj = this.toObject();
    // BELOW NOT WORKING
    delete obj.password;
    return obj;
  }
};
module.exports = User;
```

Comment: Please show how you call your model

Answer (score 18):

You are adding `toJSON` as a *class method* (outside of the `attributes` object); it needs to be an *instance method*:

```
# models/User.js
var User = {
  attributes: {
    username: 'string',
    password: 'string',

    // Override toJSON method to remove password from API
    toJSON: function() {
      var obj = this.toObject();
      delete obj.password;
      return obj;
    }

  }

};
module.exports = User;
```

This will add the `toJSON` method to every instance of `User`, and will work as you expect when doing things like `res.json()`.

Comment: This is the solution.

Comment: For reference, here's the info in the docs: https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/models.md#toobjecttojson-instance-methods

Comment: Here is the working url 
https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/models/instance-class-methods.md#toobjecttojson

Comment: This is also not supported anymore. You can find the new way here https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/model-settings#?customtojson

Answer (score 0):

If any of you out there spent the last 2 hours hunting this one down... if you are using passports, don't forget to clear out the passwords and accessTokens (unless you need them in your app...) Just hope it helps someone save time.

```
var User = {
    attributes: { 
    ...
    toJSON: function () {
        var obj = this.toObject();
        delete obj.password;
        delete obj.accessToken;
        if (obj.passports) {
            for (var i = 0; i< obj.passports.length; i++) {
                delete obj.passports[i].password;
                delete obj.passports[i].accessToken;
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }
}
```